# In outputStream/InputStream how i differentiate that these bytes are for name , email , what bytes are for picture?

Tags: android, bluetooth, inputstream, outputstream

I am creating an Android app and i would like to send image using outputStream and receive using InputStream .I want to send ( name , email , contact , picture ) from phone1--->phone2 through outputStream/InputStream how i differentiate that these bytes are for name , email , what bytes are for picture ?

Answer (score 2):

Just create a custom binary protocol, for example like this:

byte nameLength,
byte[] name,
byte emailLength,
byte[] email,
contact contact,
byte[] picture

Answer (score 1):

To handle something like this, you could send it with a particular protocol... for instance you could send:

[Phone number] but instead of this you'd have:

[identifier]--[data] then when you receive it, read the identifier and strip it from the payload and then handle it as you need to.